Pedels move after i stop
Took everything apart cleaned regreased put back together and when I pedel to check the pedels and chain keep going what would cause it and how to fix it is a 20 inch moongoose

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Could you include a video to show what's happening?  Does this happen on the stand or when riding?

This sounds like the freewheel on the rear wheel is being driven forward by the wheel still turning.

Inside there are 2~6 pawls that clack around a toothed ring and they transfer your pedal power through the chain and into the wheel's hub.  When you're coasting or pedalling slower than the wheel, the teeth push the pawls out of the way giving the "BRRRRrrr" noise of coasting.
With the chain off the teeth, you should be able to rotate the teeth clockwise with minimal force.
The easiest option is to replace this part, specially if its corroded.
If you're handy with tools, it is possible to flush out hardened grease from inside and re-lubricate it with fresh grease, or something "wetter".  Be aware there could be a hundred bearing balls inside this, so disassembly can be fun.
